# how to know the file type and name from the http response?

Tags: html

Now i can figure out is through 'Content-Disposition' and 'Content-Type'!
Is there any tips about know the file type and name from the http response?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: i want to use scrapy download some bookfiles among some domains,and i want to get the book file name and the file extension!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HTTP response is a resource, not a file, so it has neither file type nor file name.

For some resources the server uses a corresponding file to create it, like for example most images. In that case the name of the resource is usually the same as the name of the file, and the content type is derived from the file type.

For some resources the server returns a file name in the content disposition header. This can be the same as the name of a file on the server, but it can just as well be a file name that the browser sent to the server when the file was uploaded, and the data is stored under a different file name on the server, or perhaps stored in a completely different way.

Some resources are created by the server when needed, typically by running a script source or by calling some compiled code to generate it. In that case the name of the resource can correspond to a file on the server, but it's not the file that is returned but the result of processing the file.